# Populate a dropdown on selecting an option from another dropdown Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, input, laravel-4

Hope you're having a nice day and i'm much clear to describe my problem :)

I have a table of categories and a table of sub-categories. In my view, I want to let the user select a sub-category belonging to a category, for adding a product (Every product belongs to a sub-category). For that purpose, I want to show the user sub-categories when he selects a category. Like when he selects Clothes from Categories, I want to show Sub-categories like tops, shorts etc.

How do I do that? Just an idea would work.

Thanks.

Comment: Here's the idea...You get the ID of the selected Category and use that ID to fill the contents of your Sub Category DropDown

Comment: Thanks alot. I work on it right now :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

call `getJSON` in the first dropdown `onChange` and pass the selected value to url and load the results in the second dropdown. Hope this helps you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#firstdropdown").change(function () {
        var firstdropselectedvalue = $("#firstdropdown").val();
        var url = "test.php?selected=" + firstdropselectedvalue;
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, text) {
                $("#seconddropdown").append($("<option></option>").val(index).html(text));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I edited firstdropdown, seconddropdown, the url. It didn't work. But i've done it by learning from your code. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of busy and didn't logon to the site until now.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 6):

For those who are having a problem:

This is my function in my `$(document.ready(function(){}));` in my view

```
        $('#firstDropDown').change(function(){
        $.getJSON("{{ url('products/fetch-sub-category')}}", 
        { option: $(this).val() }, 
        function(data) {
            var model = $('#secondDropDown');
            model.empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                model.append("<option value='"+element.catName+"'>" + element.catName + "</option>");
            });
        });
    });
```

And this is what i'm returning from my controller

```
    $input = Input::get('option');
    $cat = Category::where('catName', '=', $input)->get();
    return Response::json($cat, 200);
```