# Looping Models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Have a problem here :)

```
$ls = '<select size="12">';
foreach(Category::all() as $k){
    $ls .= '<option>'.$k['name'].'</option>';
}
$ls.= '</select>';
return $ls;
```

This returns all data from DB but I want to retrive only data where parent = 1
so when I change

```
foreach(Category::all() as $k)
```

to

```
foreach(Category::where('parent','=',1) as $k)
```

it gets nothing to return. Help please, where is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
$categories = Category::where('parent', 1)->get(); // '=' could be omitted
foreach($categories as $category){
    //...
}
```

You have to call the `get()` method to get the query result. Also, avoid the doing code in your `view`. You can just pass the result to your view using something like this from the controller:

```
$categories = Category::where('parent', 1)->get();
return View::make('viewname')->with('categories', $categories);
```

Then loop in the View:
    // Blade
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        {{ ... }}
    @endforeach
Remove the `@` if you are not using `Blade`. But, you can also generate the `select` even without a loop, for example:

```
echo Form::select('categories', $categories, Input::old('categories'));
```

For `Blade` just use:

```
{{ Form::select('categories', $categories, Input::old('categories')) }}
```

Check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/html#drop-down-lists) and read the documentation properly, you need to.

### Don't run your queries in your `view` file, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I am not doing in View this is for AJAX call so controller will return HTML to View.

Comment: Still it's a bad idea, you can do it in other way. Just pull the `json` data from the server and build the `select` on client side.

Comment: Well how I need to get data from Database when user picks a category O want to display subcategory in that view. How can I do in other way?

Comment: I've [already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23023755/741747) it but you accepted another answer but not bad if it helps you. I thought you got it :-)